# How i can control button input android?

Tags: android, unityscript

i am android programmer and i want control button input in android
for example i made a game that when you press back button in android mobile
nothing happens but i want quite from game.

[image]
[image]

This is how you can use the android back button in Unity games.

In C#

```
void Update()
{
   if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
   {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
        Application.Quit();
   }
}
```

or in JS

```
function Update()
{
   if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
   {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
        Application.Quit();
   }
}
```

but how i can contorl other buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Home)){
        // Home button pressed
        // Write everything you want to do here
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape)){
        // Escape button pressed
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Menu)){
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```